# Arrange elements in a matrix of any size

Tags: c#, matrix, random, distribution

This is more of a discussion than a question per se since I could solve this with code but I think there should be better ways of doing this.

I need to distribute elements in a matrix so that each quadrant of the matrix (which dimensions aren't necessarily divisible by 4) contains an equal (or as close to equal as possible) number of said elements but is located randomly within that quadrant. 
The rest of the matrix needs to contain random elements of a different type.

For instance, distributing 10 elements (A) in a 9x6 matrix could look like this:

[image]

Which reveals the problem of what to do with the middle lines when a dimension is odd. It could be included on one quadrant or the other randomly (the fact that there are no As in the 3 middle columns is just chance)

I first thought of dealing with this with a recursive function that divides into quadrants and randomly places each element.

I'm halfway through coding this in C#, the idea being something like this (it doesn't work as of yet and some things are inefficient to try to make the code more readable):

```
private void PopulateQuadrants(ref Test5Target[,] matrix,
        int xBeginQuadrant, int xEndQuadrant, int yBeginQuadrant, int yEndQuadrant, int targets)
    {
        if (targets == 0)
        {
            return;
        }
        else if (targets == 1)
        {
            Random rand = new Random();
            matrix[rand.Next(xBeginQuadrant, xEndQuadrant), rand.Next(yBeginQuadrant, yEndQuadrant)]
                = new Test5Target(ChosenTarget, UseAdvancedTargets);
            for (int x = xBeginQuadrant; x < xEndQuadrant; x++)
            {
                for (int y = xBeginQuadrant; y < xEndQuadrant; y++)
                {
                    if (matrix[x, y] == null)
                    {
                        int type = rand.Next(TargetCount);
                        while(type == ChosenTarget){
                            type = rand.Next(TargetCount);
                        }

                        matrix[x, y] = new Test5Target(rand.Next(TargetCount), UseAdvancedTargets);
                    }
                }
            }

            return;
        }
        else
        {
            int[] TargetsPerQuadrant = { targets / 4, targets / 4, targets / 4, targets / 4 };
            int RemaindingTargets = targets % 4;
            Random rand = new Random();
            while (RemaindingTargets > 0)
            { // Randomly select quadrants to allocate the Remainding targets (one may end up with 3 extra as it is now)
                TargetsPerQuadrant[rand.Next(4)]++;
                RemaindingTargets--;
            }
            PopulateQuadrants(ref matrix, xBeginQuadrant, xEndQuadrant / 2, yBeginQuadrant, yEndQuadrant / 2, TargetsPerQuadrant[0]);
            PopulateQuadrants(ref matrix, xEndQuadrant / 2, xEndQuadrant, yBeginQuadrant, yEndQuadrant / 2, TargetsPerQuadrant[1]);
            PopulateQuadrants(ref matrix, xBeginQuadrant, xEndQuadrant / 2, yBeginQuadrant, yEndQuadrant / 2, TargetsPerQuadrant[2]);
            PopulateQuadrants(ref matrix, xEndQuadrant / 2, xEndQuadrant, yBeginQuadrant / 2, yEndQuadrant, TargetsPerQuadrant[3]);
        }
    }
```

Is there any mathematically correct or simple or something way of achieving this or should I keep going in this way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally decided to just place a minimum of a fourth of all elements in each corner randomly and the remainder also randomly ignoring odd lengths or just letting it skew toward one side or the other.

```
private Element[,] GetCancellationTestMatrix(int rows, int columns, int targets, int types)
    {
        // Supposing the different types of elements are just ints and we want a concrete type
        // for our targets which is contained in the variable "TargetType"
        Element[,] Matrix = new int[rows, columns];

        Random rand = new Random();
        int currQuadRowBegin = 0;
        int currQuadRowEnd = rows / 2;

        int currQuadColBegin;
        int currQuadColEnd;

        int rowIndex;
        int colIndex;
        for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++)
        {
            currQuadColBegin = 0;
            currQuadColEnd = columns / 2;
            for (int j = 0; j < 2; j++)
            {
                for (int t = 0; t < targets / 4; t++)
                {
                    rowIndex = rand.Next(currQuadRowBegin, currQuadRowEnd);
                    colIndex = rand.Next(currQuadColBegin, currQuadColEnd);
                    while (Matrix[rowIndex, colIndex] != null)
                    {
                        rowIndex = rand.Next(currQuadRowBegin, currQuadRowEnd);
                        colIndex = rand.Next(currQuadColBegin, currQuadColEnd);
                    }
                    Matrix[rowIndex, colIndex] = new Element(TargetType);
                }
                currQuadColBegin = currQuadColEnd++;
                currQuadColEnd = columns - 1;
            }
            currQuadRowBegin = currQuadRowEnd++;
            currQuadRowEnd = rows - 1;
        }

        // Some targets may be unarranged yet (up to three)
        int remainding = targets % 4;
        while (remainding > 0)
        {
            rowIndex = rand.Next(0, rows);
            colIndex = rand.Next(0, columns);
            while (Matrix[rowIndex, colIndex] != null)
            {
                rowIndex = rand.Next(0, rows);
                colIndex = rand.Next(0, columns);
            }
            Matrix[rowIndex, colIndex] = new Element(TargetType);
            remainding--;
        }

        // Fill the remainding elements of the target matrix with other targets
        List<int> fakeTargets = new List<int>(rows * columns - targets);
        // If we are placing 10 targets in a 9x6 matrix then we need to place an extra 
        // 9 * 6 - 10 = 34 targets and if we have, say, 4 types then we can divide that
        // between 4-1 (for the target type)
        int targetsOfEachType = (rows * columns - targets) / types-1; 
        for (int i = 0; i < types; i++)
        {
            if (i == TargetType) continue;
            for (int j = 0; j < targetsOfEachType; j++)
            {
                fakeTargets.Add(i);
            }
        }
        int tmp;
        while (fakeTargets.Count < rows * columns - targets)
        {
            tmp = rand.Next(types);
            while (tmp == TargetType)
            {
                tmp = rand.Next(types);
            }
            fakeTargets.Add(tmp);
        }
        Shuffle(fakeTargets); // Assume this method shuffles the list of fakeTargets 
        tmp = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < rows; i++)
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < columns; j++)
            {
                if (Matrix[i, j] != null) continue;
                Matrix[i, j] = new Element(fakeTargets[tmp++]);
            }
        }
        return Matrix;
    }
```

Of course, I'm not claiming this is a good solution, just one that works for me at least for now. I'll leave some time so that someone can post a better answer or some corrections over mine before I check this as the answer.